# RegEx - Not parsing dot(.) at the end of a sentence

Tags: c#, regex

C# .Net4.5

I have the following regEx expression

```
^([0-9A-Z.]?[0-9a-z.]*\b\s*)+$
```

What this should do is match on a sentence where the words in the sentence may have a capital at the start of the word but not after the first letter and it may have a dot(.) anywhere within the sentence.

The expression words with the following

- This Works
- Th.is Wo.rks

But it doesn't work if the dot is at the end of a word

- Does not Work.
- This. Does not Work

Why doesn't this work if the dot(.) is at the end of a word?

Comment: Because of the `\b` - remove it. See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%5b0-9A-Z.%5d%3f%5b0-9a-z.%5d*%5cs*)%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=This+Works%0d%0aTh.is+Wo.rks%0d%0aDoes+not+Work.%0d%0aThis.+Does+not+Work&o=m)

Answer (score 2):

> Why doesn't this work if the dot(.) is at the end of a word?

`\b` matches a word boundary, you don't have a period after that, so you don't get full stops at the end of words.

---

This seems closer:

```
^([0-9A-Z.]?[0-9a-z.]*(?:\b|\s)\.*)+$
```

I've added an or for word boundary and space `\b|\s` and put a period in there too.

It [matches](http://regexr.com/3cnsn) all 4 of your sample lines.

This seems cleaner:

```
^([0-9A-Z.]?[0-9a-z.]*\s*)+$
```

([Example](http://regexr.com/3cnt0))

Comment: What do you intend to match with `\s.` pattern?

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this.
the \s. will match on this ( Dot over there .  )

Comment: @user1255276 My first attempt wasn't quite right as I forgot to escape the dot, in the version I copied to the answer. regexr was OK I think.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I had a cut and paste fail between regexr and so. :-\

Comment: Yeah, my first suggestion to remove `\b` looks cleaner indeed. But you wanted to post the first :)

Comment: Why do you bother using regexr if you test a .NET regex? It only supports JavaScript regex syntax.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I was on regexr playing. Scouts honour. And because setting .net fiddle would take too long. Im open to a different playground?

Comment: See my link in the comment to the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew awesome, ive added it to my bookmarks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need word boundary `\b` since the characters are restricted
to `[A-Za-z.\s]`

Why not keep it simple and just enforce that `[A-Z]` can only exist on a whitespace
boundary. *(below, `\s` is replaced with `\h` for brevity)*

`^\h*(?:(?<!\S)[A-Z]|[\da-z.\h]+)+$`

[Formatted and tested:](http://www.regexformat.com)

```
 ^                     # BOS
 \h*                   # Optional leading whitespace
 (?:                   # Cluster group start
      (?<! \S )             # Whitespace boundary before capital
      [A-Z]                 # Single capital letter
   |                      # or,
      [\da-z.\h]+           # Multiple digits, lower case letters, dots or whitespace
 )+                    # Cluster group end, do 1 to many times
 $                     # EOS
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. I believe I finally have the answer

```
^(\s*[0-9A-Z.]?[0-9a-z.]*\b\s*[.|\s]*)+$
```

The reason I need the \b is because I need the pattern to not match on words that have capitals in the middle of the word. When the /b is removed the pattern will match on words with capitals in the middle of the word

Comment: Classes don't need an _or_ operator `|` , it is implicit. So I believe what you want there is `[.\s]`. Just some notes - the way word boundaries are used is to match a place between characters where a word character exists on one side but not the other (and visa versa).  Therefore, `\b` can match `aaaA<here>.<here>B<here>.` etc ... This is the definition of a word boundary described as a regex `(?:(?:^|(?<=[^a-zA-Z0-9_]))(?=[a-zA-Z0-9_])|(?<=[a-zA-Z0-9_])(?:$|(?=[^a-zA-Z0-9_])))` Try and substitute that into your code to see if you understand it.

Comment: In reality. You are trying to use a word boundary to control the fact that a capital must not exist in the middle of your valid word characters (plus the dot). This leave's the only place it can exist as _after_ a whitespace or the beginning of the string. This has always been called a _whitespace boundary_. To enforce it to the left you'd use `(?<!\S)` to the right you'd use `(?!\S)`. This is described as a _not_ _not whitespace_. Used this way it allows it to be matched at the beginning or end of strings as well as in the middle.

Comment: Thanks for the tips sln, much appreciated.