# Regex expression doesn't recognize dot at end of word - Regex (C++)

Tags: c++, regex, perl

I'm trying to read a line out of a file using the following `regex` expression:

```
^([A-z.]+?\\s?[A-z]+)\\s([A-z]+)\\s(\\d{7})\\s(\\d?\\d.\\d)$
```

on the line:

W.W. Sneijder 0000574 10.0

(To be clear: the intent is to make any word with chars [a-z], [A-Z], or dots, match with the [A-z.]+ part.)

However, the regular expression doesn't recognize the second dot in W.W., which seems strange to me. Don't the square brackets combined with the + mean that any character from inside them is accepted, until (here) whitespace is encountered? I found a regex that does work but isn't that elegant:

```
^([A-z.]+[.\\s?[A-z]+)\\s([A-z]+)\\s(\\d{7})\\s(\\d?\\d.\\d)$
```

I'm hoping the find an elegant solution. It'd be great to hear your input.

Links such as [RegEx - Not parsing dot(.) at the end of a sentence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35212059/regex-not-parsing-dot-at-the-end-of-a-sentence) didn't seem to answer my question unfortunately.

Comment: The second (non-optional) character group (`[]`) has no `.` allowed in it? [It works](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U8XUXvGlNw7EMw7y) if I simply add the missing dot.

Comment: What are you trying to get out of the input? What are the different fields of the input? Why have you decided to try parsing it with a regular expression? What other ways of parsing the input have you tried? I can't help but think that a regular expression to parse the whole line is way too complicated and overkill, and will just be unmaintainable.

Comment: It has no point in it because it's supposed to detect names. One could write their initials, giving one word of input (W.W.), or write them out, giving one or more: Wesley (William). Although a bit counterintuitive considering the intention of the regex, adding a dot in the second character group definitely works, so thank you for that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The input consists of just lines like the one shown above. I'm using a regex to extract the different parts and store them accordingly in a class objects, which I can then later use to sort them by, for example, grade, which is the last number. Is using regex for that a bit overkill? I'm aware that regex isn't that efficient but couldn't really think of a much better way... Thank you!

Comment: Like just about every use of regular expressions in questions on this site, parsing the input without a regular expression is almost certainly simpler and more maintainable than struggling with a (write-only) regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex, the entire `W.W. Sneijder` is captured in the first group. Looking at your regex, I doubt you intended it that way.

I think the regex you wanted is `^([A-z.]+?\s?[A-z]+)\s(\d{7})\s(\d?\d.\d)$`.
 Or if you wanted `Sneijder` to be in the second capture: `^([A-z.]+?)\s([A-z]+)\s(\d{7})\s(\d?\d.\d)$`.

... or maybe you wanted `^([A-z.]+?\s?[A-z]*)\s([A-z]+)\s(\d{7})\s(\d?\d.\d)$` (`*` instead of `+` in the first capture group).
or `^([A-z.]+?(?:\s[A-z]+)?)\s([A-z]+)\s(\d{7})\s(\d?\d.\d)$` (optional space + text, again in the first capture groups).

All 4 expressions should match your test string, but behave differently on other test strings.

---

There certainly are improvements to the regex, such as ensuring the string does not start with a `.`.

As long as you touch the **inside** of each capture group but not the logic **across** capture groups, you can let the regex manage any level of control you desire and this will have no impact on the code that follows the text parsing.
It will always be 4 capture groups, with, except the first regex I posted above that has only 3 capture groups, with some guarantees on the text if you need to convert it to another type.

Answer (score 2):

Space separated data is just a different variant of the common [CSV (Comma Separated Values)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) format. There are many ways to separate a string on arbitrary separators, but in C++ using space is actually *very* easy:

```
std::vector<std::string> separate_on_space(std::string const& input)
{
    std::vector<std::string> output;
    std::istringstream iss(input);

    // Copy all space-separated "words" from the input to the vector
    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(iss), // Begin iterator
              std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),    // End iterator
              std::back_inserter(output));             // Destination iterator

    return output;
}
```

<sub>[See example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/GMcP4j46x)]</sub>

Once you have separated the values into a vector of strings, you can then convert the numeric values to their actual type (for example using `std::stod`) and store into suitable objects.

---

Of course this doesn't handle names with spaces in them in a graceful way, but that can be handled at a higher level (by checking the size of the resulting vector, and by knowing the last two elements should always the special numbers, and the rest are the names).

On the other hand the regular expression in the question doesn't handle it at all. :)

Comment: This certainly seems less error-prone and efficient. Thank you!

Comment: ... Except you have to write checks to make sure each text in the resulting array is in the format you want. The solution above successfully parses `1 2 3 4` for instance... Now, it is going to be faster to get a clean regex or to write 4 different pieces of code, each to control the specific format of the 4 items in the table?

Comment: @Atmo Very true point. Except when you know your input data. A downside would then be of course that your code is not usable anywhere else where no such certainty exists.